# Contemporary Music note group Notation

Tags: notation, lilypond, transcription

I am writing an article about Stockhausen's Plus-Minus and I wanted to take this chance to write some snippets in LilyPond. Is there anyone willing to help me to transcribe this image?

[image: five groups of notes across two staves, note stems join into one with a single slashed grace note flag]

This is what I managed to achieve until now:

```
\version "2.24.1"
\paper { top-margin = 20\mm}
\language italiano

\score {
    \new PianoStaff  = "Subsidiary Notes"  {<<
        \new Staff {
            \clef "treble"
            \autoBeamOff
            \stemUp
            \override Stem.length = 15
            \relative {
                << sold''4 la>> 
                s8
                <<
                    \once \override Stem.length = 20
                    \single \override Stem.X-offset = #-2
                    \single \override NoteHead.X-offset = #-3 
                    lad,4
                    \single \override NoteHead.X-offset = #-2 
                    si 
                >>
                <<
                    \once \override Stem.length = 17
                    \single \override Stem.X-offset = #-15
                    \single \override NoteHead.X-offset = #-16
                    re
                    \single \override Stem.X-offset = #-15
                    \single \override NoteHead.X-offset = #-15
                    mib 
                >>
                \once \override Stem.length = 10
                \once \override NoteHead.no-ledgers = ##t
                \once \override NoteHead.transparent = ##t 
                \once \override Stem.X-offset = #-27
                \once \override Flag.stroke-style = #"grace"
                do''''8
            
            }
        }
        \new Staff {
            \autoBeamOff
            \override Stem.length = 45
            \clef "bass"
            s16
            \once \override Stem.length = 50 \crossStaff<<fad,,4 sol,,>>
            \crossStaff<<
                \once \override Stem.X-offset = #-4
                \single \override NoteHead.X-offset = #-5
                red, 
                \single \override NoteHead.X-offset = #-4 
                mi,
                >>
        }
    >>}
    \layout {
        \context {
            \Score
            \override SpacingSpanner.spacing-increment = 5
            \consists #Span_stem_engraver 
        }
    }
}
```

which gives this result:

[image: five groups of notes across two staves, withs stems reaching a common height, and slashed grace note flag above (disconnected)]

I am a new LilyPond user so, I hope that it is not to messy. I guess there is a way to templating all these `\override`s and to be more congruent in the use of `\single` and `\once`.

##### EDIT:

Probably another approach would be using 1/8th notes and creating a stencil for the beam. This does look way tidier indeed:

```
\new PianoStaff  = "Subsidiary Notes"  {
        \time 5/8
        <<
        \new Staff = "high" {
            \clef "treble"
               \override Beam.positions = #'(9 . 9)
            \relative {
                <sold'' la>8^[
                \change Staff = "low" 
                <fad,,,, sol>
                <red' mi>
                \change Staff = "high" 
                <lad''' si>
                <re mib>]
            }
            \revert Beam.positions
        }
        \new Staff = "low" {
            \clef "bass"
            s2
            s8
        }
        >>
    }
```

[image: five groups of notes across two staves, with stems reaching a common height, beamed together]

##### UPDATE:

Well I managed to come up with a solution for the Beam!
First I set it higher than the default one and the a make it invisible:

```
% inside Staff = "high"
\override Beam.positions = #'(9 . 9)
\override Beam.transparent = ##t
```

then at the end of the note group I draw the lines using a a customized `\markup` statement that I called `samplePath`:

```
% outside the score
samplePath = 
    #'(
        (moveto -13.45 6.4)
        (lineto -6 8)
        (moveto -10.95 6.4)
        (lineto -6 8)
        (moveto -6.35 6.4)
        (lineto -6 8)
        (moveto -2.96 6.4)
        (lineto -6 8)
        (moveto 1.25 6.4)
        (lineto -6 8)
        )
...
% the last chord of the group inside the Staff = "high" 
<re mib>]^\markup \path #0.1 #samplePath
```

and I get this:

[image: five groups of notes across two staves, beamed together by independent lines]

How would I position the slashed grace note flag above the line? I have been looking into the glyphs but there is no such symbol and I couldn't even align it properly. Maybe an image of it? But how would I position it correctly? Placing it in the next bar does and adding an negative `X-offset` does not work because it moves the lines.

##### NOTE:

It would be great to keep the `\time 5/8` so that I could even generate a correct MIDI file out of it

Comment: What does this notation mean?  What is the "4" for? Are all these notes meant to be played at the same time or not?

Comment: This is the "4"th of 6 groups of what Stockhausen in this score calls "Accidental Notes". They are not supposed to be played as written, but rather to be used for composing a "possible version" of the score. The rules of _Plus-Minus_ are quite complex. To simplify: there are 7 pages of simbols and seven pages of notes. The symbols indicate how to use these "Accidentals Notes" in combination of the rest of the provided material. [This article](https://stockhausenspace.blogspot.com/2015/06/plus-minus.html) gives a more detailed analysis of the piece

Answer (score 1):

A general proof of concept of how this could be done:

```
#(define (grob-extent2 grob ref axis just dir)
   (let* ((cref (ly:grob-common-refpoint grob ref axis))
          (ext (ly:grob-extent grob cref axis))
          (rext (ly:grob-extent ref cref axis))
          (rext2 (ly:grob-extent ref (ly:grob-parent ref axis) axis))
          (just (/ (1+ just) 2))
          (justv1 (+ (* just (cdr rext)) (* (- 1 just) (car rext))))
          (justv2 (if (= dir UP) (car rext2) (cdr rext2)))
          (justv (- justv2 justv1)))
     (cons (+ (car ext) justv) (+ (cdr ext) justv))))

#(define (stem-alignment stem-expr)
   (if (equal? (car stem-expr) 'translate-stencil)
       (let ((offset (list-ref stem-expr 1))
             (align (stem-alignment (list-ref stem-expr 2))))
         (if align
             (+ (car offset) align)
             align))
       (if (equal? (car stem-expr) 'combine-stencil)
           (let ((align (filter (lambda (x) x) (map stem-alignment (cdr stem-expr)))))
             (if (null? align) #f (car align)))
           (if (and (equal? (car stem-expr) 'grob-cause)
                    (member 'stem-interface (ly:grob-interfaces (list-ref stem-expr 1))))
               0
               #f))))

{
  \override Beam.after-line-breaking =
  #(lambda (grob)
     (let* ((stems (ly:grob-array->list (ly:grob-object grob 'stems)))
            (dir (ly:grob-property (car stems) 'direction))
            (exts-x (map (lambda (stem) (grob-extent2 stem grob X LEFT RIGHT)) stems))
            (exts-y (map (lambda (stem) (grob-extent2 stem grob Y CENTER dir)) stems))
            (cy (map (lambda (ext) (if (= DOWN dir) (car ext) (cdr ext))) exts-y))
            (cx (map interval-center exts-x))
            (lx (map interval-length exts-x))
            (bx (/ (+ (first cx) (last cx)) 2))
            (by (+ (/ (apply + cy) (length cy)) (* 0.5 dir)))
            (lines (map (lambda (x y w) (make-line-stencil w x y bx by)) cx cy lx))
            (stem (grob-interpret-markup grob #{
              \markup \rhythm { \omit NoteHead \override Stem.direction = #dir \slashedGrace c8 } 
                                         #}))
            (stem (ly:make-stencil (ly:stencil-expr stem) (stencil-true-extent stem X) (stencil-true-extent stem Y)))
            (stem (ly:stencil-translate-axis stem (- ( stem-alignment (ly:stencil-expr stem))) X))
            (stem (ly:stencil-aligned-to stem Y (- dir)))
            (stem (ly:stencil-translate stem (cons bx by))))
       (ly:grob-set-property! grob 'stencil (apply ly:stencil-add stem lines))))
  g'8 c' e' g'
  c'' e'' f'' c''
}
```